# Handling Slide Change Event during a PowerPoint Slide Show

Tags: office-js

We are creating an add-in for PowerPoint and need to know two things during a slideshow:

1. When the user clicks or moves to the next slide
2. When transitions or effects are completed.

In Interop on Windows, There is an event SlidesShowNextClickAsync(SlideShowWindow Wn, Effect Effects) which enables getting the slideId and knowing when all transitions and effects are done. The need is to provide this functionality on Mac where there is no Interop support.

Is there an equivalent or anything close in Office JS API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no such Office JS APIs. If you have such requirement, please log a user voice here: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback and we will triage accordingly.